# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing, magento1.9.3

I just upgraded to **Magento 1.9.3.7** via **SFTP**. When I tried to reindex all indexes and recompiled everything, I received the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception in /var/www/webroot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:1377
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/webroot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(848): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException()
#1 /var/www/webroot/public_html/app/Mage.php(353): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore(NULL)
#2 /var/www/webroot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Helper/Data.php(47): Mage::getStoreConfig('system/log/enab...')
#3 /var/www/webroot/public_html/app/Mage.php(547): Mage_Log_Helper_Data->__construct()
#4 /var/www/webroot/public_html/app/Mage.php(811): Mage::helper('log')
#5 /var/www/webroot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php(247): Mage::log('Warning: simple...', 3)
#6 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/var/w in /var/www/webroot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 1377
```

**Please suggest a solution to fix this error.**

Comment: any luck solving this issue?

Comment: Please add below lines.
----------------------- require_once 'app/Mage.php'; Mage::app('main');

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a year. But just in case somebody bumped into this issue.....

We don't have the logical explanation but in our case we have this same issue because we are missing a default config value of a config section in our custom module that we built (we have multi store Magento site).

For example, here's our configuration scope:

```
1. default config
1.1 website 1
1.1.1 store 1
1.1.2 store 2
1.2 website 2
1.2.1 store 1
1.2.2 store 2
```

In our case, we have configured everything on most websites and most stores, BUT we left the default configuration empty (unconfigured). That's why we see this error whenever we change the configuration scope.

After setting the configuration for the default scope, the issue is fixed. Hope it helps!